# GNU tar's --null option

Tags: linux, tar, manpages

The GNU tar's manpage has this to say about the `--null` option:

```
-T reads null-terminated names, disable -C
```

I know that `--null` is useful in combination with `find ... -print0`, but what is it about `disable -C`? How do null-terminated names have anything to do with the `-C` option, which is supposed to change into the directory?

What does the man page actually mean? I can think of several possibilities:

1. `--null` conflicts with `-C`, I simply can't use both together;
2. I *can*, but *should not* use `--null` and `-C` together because the result may be wrong;
3. `--null` automatically disables `-C`;

Which meaning is it?

EDIT: the version of GNU tar I have is 1.27.1, on Debian Jessie.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is a glitch. The [online info version](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC110) doesn't say anything about `disable -C` -- which as you correctly argue would not make sense -- but does say:

> ... `--null' also disables special handling for file names that begin with dash (similar to `--verbatim-files-from' option).

This makes more sense; a newline-separated list of filenames can be generated by a tool (like `find`) OR can be typed easily enough by a human who might well want to specify options also, but a null-separated list is much more likely generated by a tool and thus only filenames.